# Mongo regex query in java

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

How to write this query in java.

```
db.getCollection('recipe_qmeshm_enumerations').find({
           "values.value":/^\QbuTTer\E$/i
   })
```

I am trying to write like this but it's not giving any result.

```
Criteria criteria2 = new Criteria().where("values.value").regex("/^\QbuTTer\E$/i");
    
Query query2 = new Query();

query2.addCriteria(criteria2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to create the query by myself.
The above query could be written as

```
db.getCollection('recipe_qmeshm_enumerations').find({
           "values.value":/^Ice cream$/i 
   })
```

and in java,

```
String searchValue = "ice cream";
Criteria criteria2 = new Criteria().where("values.value").regex("^"+searchValue+"$","i");
        Query query2 = new Query(); 
        query2.addCriteria(criteria2);
        List<Document> enumsDoc = mongoAddonsTemplate.find(query2, Document.class, indexName);
```